# ora-19011 ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DECODE(GL.DOCTYPENUM,160901,'Opening Balance',(select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, a.accountdesc || ',')).extract('//text()').extract('//text()') ,',') accounts 
from generalledger gll
inner join Accounts a on ( a.accountid =  gll.accountid and gll.accountid !=103978)
where gll.voucherid=gl.voucherid)) particulars from generalledger gl
```

I am running a SQL query, when running the query it gives me the error

> ora-19011 character string buffer too small.

When checking the query the above code gives an error, unable to figure out where to make the change.

Thanks!

Comment: The error is pretty clear . . . your `xmlagg()` is working on data that is too large.

Comment: Any idea on how we can edit that statement to incorporate all the data

Comment: This question has been asked before; see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35729840/3061852